# How to launch Visual Studio Code terminal as a different user

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I'm starting to work with Visual Studio Code to do some PowerShell Work, and so far I do enjoy the experience/environment. The only struggle that I am facing is that I normally run PowerShell with two different accounts:

1. One is my normal domain account that I login to my computer with
2. The seconds is a domain admin account that I only use when necessary

I figured how to open up multiple terminals at once, but now if I could figure out how to open a terminal as a different user (without needing to relaunch the entire program as that user) that would be optimal. I did a little searching and wasn't able to find any similar questions, most of them are asking how to open multiple terminals but not as a different user.

Comment: I don't believe the vscode terminal emulator supports what you're trying to do.  The terminals spawn as the process-owner.

Comment: Dang, would be a nice feature! Thanks @TheIncorrigible1

Comment: You could [open a feature request on their page](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode).  Just submit an issue

Comment: I actually found that page and made one already!

Comment: For now your workaround can be having two instances of vscode open as different user contexts pointing at the same workspace root.

Comment: Already Implemented or still actual, guys?