# Visual Studio Code administrator mode behaviour makes PowerShell in Visual Studio Code terminal unusable

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

If I open an instance of Visual Studio Code in
administrator mode, then I cannot open another instance of Visual Studio Code at all until I close the administrator mode instance. Nor can I open any files in the administrator mode instance using [Windows Explorer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Explorer). Apparently, this is considered useful and by design, although I can't for the life of me see what's useful about it.

However, Visual Studio Code is the Microsoft recommended way to do PowerShell scripting, but PowerShell in the Visual Studio Code terminal won't work unless Visual Studio Code is opened in administrator mode because PowerShell requires administrator mode in order to do anything.

So if I open Visual Studio Code in administrator mode, I can't open any files, or any other Visual Studio Code instances, but if it's not in administrator mode, PowerShell won't work. How is that supposed to work?

Comment: How is this not a duplicate?

Comment: What version of Visual Studio Code? It *could* have been broken by an update (there are instances of this).

Comment: Related: *[I have to open Visual Studio Code as administrator or I won't be able to open a terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72104786/i-have-to-open-visual-studio-code-as-administrator-or-i-wont-be-able-to-open-a)*

Comment: [Visual Studio Code v1.60.0 had a bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69047142/vscode-is-suddenly-defaulting-to-powershell-for-integrated-terminal-and-tasks/69050730#69050730).

Comment: Related: *[Visual Studio Code terminal is failing to launch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63202834/visual-studio-vs-code-code-terminal-is-failing-to-launch)*

Comment: Related: *[How to launch Visual Studio Code terminal as a different user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52390289/how-to-launch-visual-studio-code-terminal-as-different-user)*

Comment: Related: *[How can I run a command with administrator rights with Visual Studio code terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37700536/visual-studio-code-terminal-how-to-run-a-command-with-administrator-rights)*. E.g. *"this error can also occur if files are locked by Windows"*

Comment: Perhaps [the attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37700536/how-can-i-run-a-command-with-administrator-rights-with-visual-studio-code-termin/76517999#76517999) should be documented.

Comment: None of the posts you've linked are anything to do with the question I'm asking here. You are linking posts about people trying to change the default terminal from cmd.exe to bash, people who can't open the terminal at all, and how to run the terminal in admin mode. None of those is what I'm asking here.